# count the number of occurrences of items in a list that appear in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to specify a list of characters/strings and find out how many occurrences from the list are in a given string.

```
const match = ['&', '|', '-', 'abc'];
const input = 'This & That | Or | THIS - Foo abc';
```

result should return `5`.

I can loop over the match and do `indexOf` with a counter, but I'm wondering if there is some easier way with `reduce`.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: are the match options only ever going to be a single character? is case important to the matching? (ie. `T =/= t`)

Comment: no, it may be a string of characters for one match.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looping over the `match` array, you could split the `input` string, filter it, and then get the length.

Here is a simple one-liner:

```
input.split('').filter(x => match.indexOf(x) > -1).length;
```

Snippet:

```js
const match = ['&', '|', '-'];
const input = 'This & That | Or | THIS - Foo';
const count = input.split('').filter(x => match.indexOf(x) > -1).length;

console.log(count); // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp to find the matching characters:

```
function escape(chr) { return '\\' + chr; }

input.match(new RegExp(match.map(escape).join('|'), "g")).length
```

The escaping is necessary to avoid problems with characters such as `|` which have special meaning in regexps.

Comment: If the `match` array consists of values such as `['&', '|', '-', '#']`, then it will throw the error `/[&|-#]/: Range out of order in character class` [(example)](https://jsfiddle.net/v16gjqq0/), because `|-#` is interpreted as a range since it is inside of a character class... You would need to escape the values if you are using this method... `['\\&', '\\|', '\\-', '\\#']`.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for reduce:

```
let count = Array.prototype.reduce.call(input, (counter, chr) => (counter + (match.indexOf(chr)!==-1 ? 1: 0)), 0)
```

UPDATED:

Based on comments on other answers, OP would like the ability to also search substrings like 'abc' in addition to individual characters. Here's a more elegant solution which you can put in a local module.

There are 2 functions that work together: one escapes the special characters in match, the other does the counting. And using reduce again...

```js
    
// This escapes characters
const escapeRegExp = (str) => (
  str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")
)
    
// This returns the count
const countMatches = (input, match, i = true) => (
  match.reduce((c, pattern) => (
    c + input.match(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(pattern), (i ? 'ig' : 'g'))).length
  ), 0)
)
    
// OP's test case
let match = ['&', '|', '-'],
    input = 'This & That | Or | THIS - Foo',
    count = countMatches(input, match)
console.log('Expects 4: ', count, 4 === count)
    
    
// Case Sensitive Test
match = ['abc']
input = 'This ABC & That abc | Or | THIS - Foo'
    
count = countMatches(input, match, false)
console.log('Expects 1: ', count, 1 === count)
    
// Case Insensitive Test
count = countMatches(input, match)
console.log('Expects 2: ', count, 2 === count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  use `.map()`, `.filter()`, with `.reduce()` chained to add element of resulting array

```js
const match = ['&', '|', '-'];
const input = 'This, & That | Or | THIS - Foo';

let res = match
         .map(v => [...input].filter(c => c === v).length)
         .reduce((a, b) => a + b)

console.log(res);
```

You can also use `for..of` loop to iterate each character, `String.prototype.contains()`, if supported, or `.some()`, to check if character is within joined string `match`.

```
 let n = 0;
 let m = match.join("");
 for (let str of input) m.contains(str) && (n += 1);
```

```
for (let str of input) match.some(s => s === str) && (n += 1);
```